# How to Ignore WCF servie XML response ordering while Deserialization XML to Service Object

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf

I am getting WCF service response as XML.But while I am trying to

De-serialization  that XML to Object,I am getting NULL for some properties.But

I have values for those properties in XML.When I see the Proxy class they

mentioned Ordering like

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ALARMDATA",

Order = 42)] for all properties.Because of this order I am getting null values.

I tried to change the order of those properties in proxy class then it is

working fine.But this not good approach. Here I don't have control over 
service and Proxy class changes
Please help me on this.